# C# sending Datagridview data to textbox in another form

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, winforms, datagridview

i have to form in first form there is datagrid view in which all patient records are showing and in second form new or update patient's form. when i click on update button from first form on any patient then all the data from datagrid view fills the textboxes of second form.
in main form i have created a method of adding textbox with gridview data here is the method

```
public void datainsert(int i)
{
   if (dgvPatientData.Rows.Count != 0)
   {
      form.txtpk.Text = dgvPatientData.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
      form.txtacc.Text = dgvPatientData.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
      form.accdate.Text = dgvPatientData.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
      form.txtssn.Text = dgvPatientData.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
      form.txtregno.Text = dgvPatientData.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value.ToString();
      form.txtlname.Text = dgvPatientData.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value.ToString();
      form.txtfname.Text = dgvPatientData.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value.ToString();
      form.dob.Text = dgvPatientData.Rows[i].Cells[7].Value.ToString();
      form.txtyears.Text = dgvPatientData.Rows[i].Cells[8].Value.ToString();
      form.txtmonths.Text = dgvPatientData.Rows[i].Cells[9].Value.ToString();
      form.combogender.Text = dgvPatientData.Rows[i].Cells[10].Value.ToString();
      form.txtaddress.Text = dgvPatientData.Rows[i].Cells[11].Value.ToString();
      form.txtzip1.Text = dgvPatientData.Rows[i].Cells[12].Value.ToString();
      form.txtzip2.Text = dgvPatientData.Rows[i].Cells[13].Value.ToString();
      form.txtstate1.Text = dgvPatientData.Rows[i].Cells[14].Value.ToString();
      form.txtstate2.Text = dgvPatientData.Rows[i].Cells[15].Value.ToString();
      form.txtphone.Text = dgvPatientData.Rows[i].Cells[16].Value.ToString();
      form.txtfax.Text = dgvPatientData.Rows[i].Cells[17].Value.ToString();
      form.txtchart.Text = dgvPatientData.Rows[i].Cells[18].Value.ToString();
      form.txtpn.Text = dgvPatientData.Rows[i].Cells[19].Value.ToString();
      form.Show();
      this.Visible = false;
   }
}
```

and from update button i am calling the above method

```
private void btnupdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   var currentRow = dgvPatientData.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
   datainsert(currentRow);
}
```

****The Problem is i am adding previous button on second form** and when i passing datagridview row index -1 one it does not work

i want that when i click previous or next button the data from datagrid view show on all textboxes.
Thanks in Advance

[Second Form of patient registration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R3C52.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the following:

```
private void btnupdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var currentRow = dgvPatientData.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
        datainsert(currentRow - 1);

    }
```

I've added "-1" inside the datainsert call. I believe, since currentRow is an int, datainsert(currentRow - 1) should work.

Let me know if this works.

Are you getting a specific error message? That would be useful to know in trying to help you resolve your issue.

Comment: @Moeed I'm sorry, I don't understand.

Comment: update button  is working fine all the datagridview fields are correctly inserted in textbox of another form

the problem is with previous button on second form. when i create instance of main form in second form and called the method of move_previous in which coding is 
dgvPatientData.Rows[dgvPatientData.Rows.Count - 1].Selected = true;
            dgvPatientData.CurrentCell = dgvPatientData.Rows[dgvPatientData.Rows.Count - 1].Cells[1];
its shows error Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index

Comment: Ah thank you this is more clear. I think I may have an idea but what to make sure first. At what point does this error occur? When you create the second form? When you click the 'previous' button on the second form without first clicking 'next' button?

Comment: thanks bro for helping. Actually previous button is placed in second form. when i click previous button then it should pick the previous row from datagridview and put all fields from datagrid view to texboxes. Understand? i am just working on previous button not coded next button yet

Comment: @Moeed You're welcome. I understand it's a work in progress. **When does the error, "Index was out of range." occur?** (Does it occur when you click the previous button?)

Comment: yes it occur when i click the previous button. i think row no i not subtracting minus 1 or may b there is some issue with datatype of row number don't know
can i send you whole code? so that you can understand?

Comment: @Moeed From what you describe, I believe what you need to do to resolve your issue is to check if your current index is 0 or check if your current row count is 0. I believe you're trying to view previous when the previous doesn't exist, so you want to implement code to prevent that. You might also want to add a message box to notify the user. If you want to send me your code, I would try to look at it as well.

Comment: yes thank alot. there is some issue with creating new instance. basically in previous button i was creating a new instance of main_view and in new main_view there is no current row so that is why no previous row is selected. thanks for your help i really appreciate it.

Comment: @Moeed You're welcome. If you need more help, be sure to post the code you're working with, the error message you're receiving, and any possible solutions you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check if your [RowIndex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcell.rowindex(v=vs.110).aspx) is not -1 when calling `datainsert` function.

An alternative is to get selected row index using:

```
dgvPatientData.SelectedRows[0].Index
```

Of course, you should check that you have at least one selected row (there should be a maximum of one if multiple row selection is not allowed).

A little offtopic, but might be useful. I would use [String indexer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ee9kshd(v=vs.110).aspx) of DataGridViewCellCollection. So, instead of:

```
gvPatientData.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value
```

it is recommended to use something like:

```
gvPatientData.Rows[i].Cells["RegNo"].Value
```

This is particularly important when you will be asked to put a column in the middle of the existing columns.